# The Boolean algebra of regularly open sets in a topological space is complete

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, boolean-algebra

To prove that regular open (Boolean) algebra is complete, I tried to show following claim, but I couldn't. I saw this statement in Kunen's 'Set Theory' p.64 but in other books what I checked, describing regular open algebra, there is no mention of the infimum of an arbitrary family of regular open sets. Is the claim really true? or an errata?

**Context**. $X$ is a topological space.

**Definition**. $b\subset X$ is a regular open set iff $b=\rm{int}(\rm{cl}(b))$ and $b$ is open. $\rm{ro}(X)$ is the set of all regular open sets in $X$.

**Context**. $\{{b_i}\}_{i\in I}$ is a family of regular open sets

**Claim**. $\rm{int}(\underset{i\in I}{\bigcap}b_i)$ is a regular open set. (so that any subset of $\rm{ro}(X)$ has infimum)

Answer (score 7):

It’s correct. Let $U=\operatorname{int}\bigcap_{i\in I}b_i$. Then $U\subseteq b_i$ for each $i\in I$, so $\operatorname{cl}U\subseteq\operatorname{cl}b_i$ for each $i\in I$. Let $V$ be any open subset of $\operatorname{cl}U$; then for each $i\in I$ we have $V\subseteq\operatorname{cl}b_i$ and hence $V\subseteq\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}b_i=b_i$. Thus, $V\subseteq\bigcap_{i\in I}b_i$, and it follows that $V\subseteq U$ and hence that $U=\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}U\in\operatorname{ro}(X)$.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, $b_n=(\frac{-1}{n}, \frac{1}{n})$ are regular open sets of $\mathbb{R}^2$. But $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n = \{0\}$ which is not open. What am I missing?

Comment: @AliDursun: Those sets are in $\Bbb R$, not $\Bbb R^2$, but yes, your sets $b_n$ are regular open sets in $\Bbb R$. What you’re missing is that $\bigwedge_nb_n$, the meet of those sets, is not $\bigcap_nb_n$: it’s $\operatorname{int}\bigcap_nb_n$, which is the regular open set $\varnothing$.